# How to measure good or bad luck in roulette

Tags: probability, variance, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I want to analyze and represent the performance of a bet (X numbers out of 37 total roulette numbers) for a series of spins (N spins).

For example, let's say that I choose 5 numbers (my bet) and these 5 numbers win in 10 out of 100 spins.

How can I measure (and show) how lucky or unlucky I was? What if I use a scale from 1 to 10.. 1 for worst results against my favour, 5 neutral and 10 for most favourable results.

I thought about comparing the actual win % to the expected average win %, but i don't really know how to do it.

As for visualizing the results, I would like to represent variance/deviation/luck with a bar like that[image]

Comment: How do you define “luck”? My proposal is to count how many angels did help you. Seriously: roulette is random, every number has equal chance of winning. From pure probability theory you can calculate what is the probability of winning, no luck involved.

Comment: I define "luck" as the difference between average expected results to actual results.

Comment: In the long run it’s zero.

Comment: I want to analyze specific definitive results. Please read the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p$ be the true probability of your bet winning in a single spin (what you call the "average win" probability).

The number of wins $X$ in $n$ spins follows a $\text{Binom}(n, p)$ distribution. When $n$ is large, this roughly follows the normal distribution $N(np, \sqrt{np(1-p)})$. The "luckiness" or "surprisingness" of the actual number of wins you get in the $n$ spins can be expressed in the form of how far you are from the mean $np$.

- One way to do this is to report the $Z$-score $\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$. This will be a real number (that usually is between $-2$ and $2$) that counts how many standard deviations you are away from the mean. A score near zero means you are quite close to the mean (which is typical), a large score means you won much more often than expected, and a very negative score means you won much less than you expected. (You can translate this to your scale from $1$ to $10$ if you wish, although I do not really see a reason to do so.)
- Another way to do this is to report the tail probability, i.e. "what is the probability of being farther from the mean than I already am?" For example, if $p=1/2$ and $n=100$, and you got $60$ wins, you might say "that's higher than $50$. What is the probability of getting $\ge 60$ wins in $100$ spins?" Here, $P(X \ge 60) \approx 2.5\%$, so you would consider yourself quite lucky. If you are under the mean, you can compute the probability of the left tail to see how unlucky you were. (Note that computing the probability $P(X=60)$ is not very informative. Even the most likely event $X=np$ has a small probability.)

---

Edit: Note that in my last bullet point (and comment below), I used $n=100$ and $p=1/2$ as an example. As BruceET points out, your situation has $p=5/37$ and $n=100$.

Comment: Very helpful! Though the first method seems clearer to me, could you please add how you calculate P(X≥60)?

Comment: @IXN You can check that $60$ is two standard deviations above the mean when $n=100$ and $p=1/2$. I know that [$95\%$ of the mass of a normal distribution lies within two standard deviations of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), so the left tail and right tail each have $2.5\%$.

Comment: Probability of more than 60 Successes is almost 0. In R, `1-pbinom(60, 100, 5/37)` actually returns $0.$ In terms of @angryavian's (+1) method of normal approximation 60 is more than 11 standard deviations above the mean, whereas almost all of the probability is contained within three standard deviations of the mean. // Also, look at the graph in my Answer.

Comment: I actually used your first method with -3 +3 as range. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

On each spin of a roulette wheel with 37 slots, you have $1$ chance in $37.$ If you bet on $5$ numbers on a spin, you have probability $5/37$ of winning. Assuming that spins of the wheel are independent, the number of wins in $100$ spins has a binomial
distribution with $n=100$ and Success probability $p=5/37.$ On average, you can
expect about $E(X) = 100(5/37) = 500/37 = 13.48631 \approx 13.5$ wins in $n=100$ spins.

You can google `binomial` distribution on the Internet, or look in an elementary probability book, to see if you can find a discussion at your level.

Here is a graph of the distribution of $X,$ showing the probability of getting each number of Successes from $0$ through $100.$

```
x = 0:100;  pdf = dbinom(x, 100, 5/37)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2, main="Distribution of BINOM(100,5/37)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 9.5, col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

The probability of getting 9 Successes or fewer is $P(X \le 9) = 0.1167$ and so
the probability of getting at least 10 successes is $1 - 0.1157 = 0.8833.$
As you can see, it is very unlikely to get more than about 25 Successes in 100 spins.

```
pbinom(9, 100, 5/37)
[1] 0.1166582
1 - pbinom(9, 100, 5/37)
[1] 0.8833418
```

Here is a mathematical formula for finding each probability $P(X = k),$ for each $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots, n=100.$

$$P(X = k) = {100 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

As computed in R statistical software, here is a table of the first fiew probabilities rounded to four places. These are the heights of the black bars in the figure above. (You can ignore the line numbers in brackets `[ ]`.)

```
x = 0:25;  PDF = round(dbinom(x, 100, 5/37), 5)
cbind(x, PDF)
       x     PDF
 [1,]  0 0.00000
 [2,]  1 0.00001
 [3,]  2 0.00006
 [4,]  3 0.00031
 [5,]  4 0.00116
 [6,]  5 0.00347
 [7,]  6 0.00859
 [8,]  7 0.01803
 [9,]  8 0.03274
[10,]  9 0.05230
[11,] 10 0.07436
[12,] 11 0.09506
[13,] 12 0.11016
[14,] 13 0.11652
[15,] 14 0.11314
[16,] 15 0.10135
[17,] 16 0.08413
[18,] 17 0.06495
[19,] 18 0.04680
[20,] 19 0.03156
[21,] 20 0.01997
[22,] 21 0.01189
[23,] 22 0.00667
[24,] 23 0.00353
[25,] 24 0.00177
[26,] 25 0.00084
```

Answer (score 4):

Gambling has the scoring built-in. Just track how much money you lose (or win)!

Comment: +1: This is one of several directly relevant possible responses.  On the other hand, I can't help feeling it could be greatly expanded into a more actionable measure of "luck," as requested in the question.  For instance, even attaching a standard error to the amount of money won would be informative.  (It would be truly informative in a game where skill is involved rather than a game of pure luck like Roulette--almost by definition, *any* amount of winnings or losses must be attributed to luck alone and so an accurate "luckometer" ought to be stuck at 100%!)

Comment: Surely it is 100% luck. But I want to measure if it is in my favor or not and how much so.

Comment: If you are using a roulette wheel in a casino, I think you can assume it is working properly and so everything is luck. You ask about if luck IS in your favor. That is not a question that can be answered. What can be answered is if luck WAS recently in your favor, but that just describes the past and won't predict the future. In a casino, seems to me the best way to quantify past luck is to ask how much money you lost (or won).